# HP-UX - Unable to use the backspace on ssh connection

Tags: keyboard, hp-ux

I have a handful of HP-UX machines that I have to work on and it really annoying to have to use the left arrow key for a backspace and have backspace type '^?'.   The systems are using HP-UX 11.31. Is there a command or a series of commands that will cause the HP-UX os to correctly align with the modern keyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `stty erase <press backspace>`.